# Using simple_html_dom to check for only part of the class name

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Sorry if the title of this question is poor. Allow me to explain myself (but do bear in mind that I am new to programming, and even newer to StackOverflow, both of which I am loving).

Basically I am scraping data from a particular cell in an HTML table on Site X. The name of the particular cell would be something like id="xyz/part_to_check/". In other words, I need to have simple_html_dom only pull data from the cell that has the class id that ENDS with a particular name, while avoiding other cells who's name might all begin with the same thing.

When I tell simple_html_dom to check for a cell, it would be something like

```
$html->find("a[href="name of cell goes here"]");
```

How can I have the "name of cell" only be for cells who's name ENDS with what I want to?

I hope I was somewhat clear here. I do apologize if I wasn't. Again, new to this whole thing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `$` before the `=` sign:

```
$html->find('a[href$="someValue"]');
//                 ^ This indicates that the href should END with that string.
```